# Sort xml atributes by value

Tags: xml, windows, sorting

I have a large xml file that i want to sort by atributes value.
The orginal file is close to 90 mb. The files purpose is a product feed.
I've prepared a examplecode to describe a bit better
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductForm>
<ProductInfo>
<StockCode>6267</StockCode>
<ProdDesc1>JACKET</ProdDesc1>
<ProdDesc2>SIZE: M</ProdDesc2>
<ModelCode>5475</ModelCode>
</ProductInfo>
<ProductInfo>
<StockCode>5678</StockCode>
<ProdDesc1>JACKET</ProdDesc1>
<ProdDesc2>SIZE: M</ProdDesc2>
<ModelCode>1876</ModelCode>
</ProductInfo>
<ProductInfo>
<StockCode>3475</StockCode>
<ProdDesc1>JACKET</ProdDesc1>
<ProdDesc2>SIZE: M</ProdDesc2>
<ModelCode>2341</ModelCode>
</ProductInfo>
</ProductForm>
```

I want it to bo sorted by the  atributes value.
So the output should be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductForm>
<ProductInfo>
<StockCode>6267</StockCode>
<ProdDesc1>JACKET</ProdDesc1>
<ProdDesc2>SIZE: M</ProdDesc2>
<ModelCode>1876</ModelCode>
</ProductInfo>
<ProductInfo>
<StockCode>5678</StockCode>
<ProdDesc1>JACKET</ProdDesc1>
<ProdDesc2>SIZE: M</ProdDesc2>
<ModelCode>2341</ModelCode>
</ProductInfo>
<ProductInfo>
<StockCode>3475</StockCode>
<ProdDesc1>JACKET</ProdDesc1>
<ProdDesc2>SIZE: M</ProdDesc2>
<ModelCode>5475</ModelCode>
</ProductInfo>
</ProductForm>
```

How can i acheive to do this?
Is this possible to do with tools like Notepad ++?

Comment: I don't think you can do it w/ notepad++. You can do it using xquery, but not sure how the file size will affect performance.

Comment: It is possible with Notepad++ **XMl Tools** plugin and XSLT transformation. Alas, it is not clear how XML shall be sorted, and the XML has no attributes, just elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try Xml Linq with Powershell

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$infos = $xDoc.Descendants("ProductInfo")
foreach($info in $infos)
{
   $sortedElements = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy($info.Elements(), [Func[object, string]] {param($x) $x.Name.LocalName}) 
   $nodes1 = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]
 
   $sortedElements | ForEach({$nodes1.Add($_)})
   
   $info.RemoveAll()
   $info.Add($nodes1)
}

$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```